# Bash script - Finding files and manipulating paths

Tags: bash-scripting, sh

So I'm attempting to write a script that achieves the following:

1. Reads file UID from a text file
2. Searches for file location based on the UID
3. Copies the file, including it's path structure to a new location.

We have medias that are currently being transferred manually, which I want to automate. Each media has a UID, which are altogether in a single file. The media is in a specific location, I know where the parent directory is, but not the individual directory of each media item.

Currently my approach is the following:

- While loop until end of file with UID
- Find matching media's path based on the UID
- Output path to temp file as the structure of the media directory matters, an example of the path structure '../Medias/Shirts/shirtA.jpg', '../Medias/Shirts/shirtA_1.jpg', or '../Medias/Pants/pantsA.jpg'
- Use temp file to copy Media to new location, i.e. 'cp $MEDIAPATH/$UID* $TARGET'

So I have two questions:

1. There are a lot of media items, I am using find and dirname and I am testing with some smaller sample data, I'm am certain there is a more efficient way to do this than mine? `FILEDIR="$(dirname "$(find ${MEDIADIR} -name "$UID" )")"`
2. Now for the copying the media to it's new location, I am unsure how to do this because I am not interested in the entire path, i.e. the path for the media item might be '/home/user/media/pants/pantsA.jpg' whereas I only need the /pants/, because when copying I want to maintain this stucture, i.e. '../targetDIR/pants/', etc?

Comment: So let me get this stright, you have a file with a list of UID that you know are attached to a file name, for example UID of "1" is attached to shirtA.jpg and UID of "2" is attached to pantA.jpg? `UID 1=shirtA.jpg` or is the $UID actually the name of the file?

Comment: Sorry I can see the confusion and you are correct in your reasoning. A mistake on my part. So to clarify the UID is say 123, in the pants directory there could be 100 media files, I want to take the media file that matches the UID, i.e. UID = 123 so we take 123.jpg